# How do you diagnose why a keyboard shortcut does not work?

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to get Command+Alt+Shift+L to work in RStudio on OSX. I have a large number of customisations that might possibly prevent this shortcut from working. I've gone through the usual places (e.g., system preferences - keyboard; Alfred; Better Touch tool). Thus, I thought there might be some more general procedure for working out what program, if any, is intercepting the shortcut

**Is there a way of seeing what program might be intercepting a particular keyboard shortcut?**

Comment: does anything happens when you do it ?

Comment: you could look it up in system pref keyboard, shortcuts

Comment: @Buscar웃 Nothing overt happens, when I press the key; I've already looked up system pref keyboard, and I couldn't see anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is app called KeyCue that will help you find the keyboard shortcuts in use by your system.

[image]

It is shareware.

More info and to download : http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/

Comment: Thanks; From what I can tell, KeyCue does not list all shortcuts. For example, it did not list BetterTouchTool global keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Stupid question, Do the other shortcuts work in RStudio ?

Comment: yes. the other shortcuts work in Rstudio

Comment: sometimes and do not ask why, try the right hand alt key

Comment: I think it is the Command+Alt+Shift+(I) or Command+Alt+Shift+l not Command+Alt+Shift+L